# SocketOptions SO_REUSEPORT integer value

Tags: linux, sockets

I want to know the integer value for the flag `SO_REUSEPORT`.

While searching I have found [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c617f398edd4db2b8567a28e899a88f8f574798d)

SO_REUSEPORT has been defined by value 0x0200 which means 512, and at other place it was SO_REUSEPORT 15.

What is the correct integer value that should be used to set the Reuse-Port option for Socket.

Answer (score 1):

The value depends on the operating version you use.
Don't use a hard-coded value but use the system specific definition.

Comment: `grep -r SO_REUSEPORT /usr/include/` gives `/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h:#define SO_REUSEPORT  15`, but make sure to re-check on your system. Such values might even depend on libc versions etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the architecture. On older architectures like mips, alpha, and sparc, where BSD (and SVR4 and Solaris and OSF/1) defined most of the SO_* socket options as single-bit flags that could be ORed together, Linux uses the pre-existing values. But on x86 platforms, Linux uses sequential small integers.

It's best to `#include <sys/socket.h>` and get the values from there.